# Batch append images in groups of two with Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have a directory of images and need to merge those images horizontally in groups of two, then save the output of each to a new image file:

```
image-1.jpeg
image-2.jpeg
image-3.jpeg
image-4.jpeg
image-5.jpeg
image-6.jpeg
```

Using Imagemagick via command line, is there a way to loop through every other image in a directory and run `magick convert image-1.jpeg image-2.jpeg +append image-combined-*.jpg`?

So the result would be combined pairs of images:

```
image-1.jpeg image-2.jpeg -> image-combined-1.jpg
image-3.jpeg image-4.jpeg -> image-combined-2.jpg
image-5.jpeg image-6.jpeg -> image-combined-3.jpg
```

Comment: Does it matter which image is paired with which? Your OS may be important!

Comment: Ah yes, I'm on OSX. And yes, the images need to be paired sequentially in groups of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be scripted easily using ImageMagick. I could show you how in Unix. But if you have more than 9 images, then you may have to rename with leading zeros, since alphabetically image-10 will come before image-2. You do not mention your IM version or platform and scripting will differ depending upon OS.

Here is a Unix solution. I have images rose-01.jpg ... rose-06.jpg in folder test on my desktop (Mac OSX). Each image has a label under it with its filename so we can keep track of the files.

```
cd
cd desktop/test
arr=(`ls *.jpg`)
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i=i+2)); do
j=$((i+1))
k=$((i+2))
magick ${arr[$i]} ${arr[$j]} +append newimage_${j}_${k}.jpg
done
```

Note that arrays start with index 0. So I use j=i+1 and k=i+2 for the images that correspond to 1,2 3,4 5,6 in the filenames from ls in the array.

The result is (newimage_1_2.jpg, newimage_3_4.jpg, newimage_5_6.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly after adding leading zeros to my images. I was mainly curious if Imagemagick offered any iterator functions to handle this, but your solution is very simple. Thanks!

Comment: If you liked my answer, please consider up-voting it. I do not believe that command line ImageMagick supports an iterator. But one of the API's might. Unfortunately, I only use command line mode.

Answer (score 4):

Get them all appended succinctly and in parallel with **GNU Parallel** and actually use all those lovely CPU cores you paid **Intel** for!

```
parallel -N2 convert {1} {2} +append combined-{#}.jpeg ::: *jpeg
```

where:

- `-N2` says to take two files at a time
- `{1}` and `{2}` are the first two parameters
- `{#}` is the sequential job number, and
- `:::` demarcates the start of the parameters

If your CPU has 8 cores, **GNU Parallel** will run 8 `converts` at once, unless you specify say 4 jobs at a time by adding `-j4`.

---

If you are learning and just finding your way with **GNU Parallel** add:

- `--dry-run` so you can see what it would do without actually doing anything
- `-k` to keep the outputs in order

So, I mean:

```
parallel --dry-run -k -N2 convert {1} {2} +append combined-{#}.jpeg ::: *jpeg
```

**Sample Output**

```
convert image-1.jpeg image-2.jpeg +append combined-1.jpeg
convert image-3.jpeg image-4.jpeg +append combined-2.jpeg
convert image-5.jpeg image-6.jpeg +append combined-3.jpeg
```

---

On **macOS**, you can simply install **GNU Parallel** with:

```
brew install parallel
```

---

If you have thousands, or hundreds of thousands of files, you may run into an error `Argument list too long` - although this is pretty rare on macOS because the limit is 262,144 characters:

```
sysctl -a kern.argmax
kern.argmax: 262144
```

If that happens, you can use this syntax to pipe the filenames in **GNU Parallel** instead:

```
find /somewhere -iname "*.jpeg" -print0 | parallel -0 -N2 convert {1} {2} +append combined-{#}.jpeg
```

Comment: `find` will search recursively in `/somewhere`. If you only want current dir: `printf '%s\0' * | parallel ...`. This works because `printf` is a builtin function that does not have to respect the argmax limit.

Comment: Hi Mark, how can I use your cool command above if it is not a pair of two pictures, but a set of 18 subsequent pictures of about 234 pictures (so the first combined picture from picture 1 to 18, then the second from picture 19 to 36, etc), so that I would get 13 combined pictures in total, each containing 18 pictures of the set?

Answer (score 2):

If the images are all the same size and orientation, and if your system has the memory to read in all the images in the directory, it can be done as simply as this...

```
magick *.jpeg -set option:doublewide %[fx:w*2] \
   +append +repage -crop %[doublewide]x%[h] +repage image-combined-%02d.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is to montage all the images together two-by-two as an array of 2x3 and then equally crop them into 3 sections vertically. So in ImageMagick, this also works since these images are all the same size.

```
cd
cd desktop/test
arr=(`ls *.jpg`)
num=${#arr[*]}
num2=`magick xc: -format "%[fx:ceil($num/2)]" info:`
magick montage ${arr[*]} -tile 2x -geometry +0+0 miff:- | magick - -crop 1x3@ +repage newimage.jpg
```

The results are: newimage-0.jpg, newimage-1.jpg, newimage-2.jpg

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ole Tang wrote:

> Fails on filenames like My summer photo.jpg

So here is the solution using ImageMagick as modified from my original post.

Images:

rose 1.png
rose 2.png
rose 3.png
rose 4.png
rose 5.png
rose 6.png

```
OLDIFS=IFS
IFS=$'\n'
arr=(`ls *.png`)
for ((i=0;i<6;i++)); do
echo "${arr[$i]}"
done
IFS=OLDIFS
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i=i+2)); do
j=$((i+1))
k=$((i+2))
magick "${arr[$i]}" "${arr[$j]}" +append newimage_${j}_${k}.jpg
done
```

This produces:

newimage_1_2.jpg
newimage_3_4.jpg
newimage_5_6.jpg